# How to set memsize in SAS 9.3 on Windows 7?

Tags: sas

I am getting a memory error from sas

> ERROR: Unable to allocate sufficient memory: a request for 1578243K
>   bytes exceeded the 1408198K
>          available. Note that the deficit amount may not be the amount of memory needed for a
>          successful run, since it does not reflect subsequent allocations by this or other
>          processes. ERROR: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of insufficient 
>          memory.

I right-clicked the shortcut and added -memsize 9000M onto the end of the target

It still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the memsize option can only be set in the configuration .cfg file.

Comment: Thanks.  I have since tried that it doesn't seem to be having any effect.  Im completely baffled on this.

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve? Are you using PROC FREQ with several variables? If so, use a PROC SUMMARY instead.

Comment: Im trying to use PROC MIXED - I think it could be some kind of error in my code now but I dont know why its resulting in the memory error message